# Content Security Policy blocks my locale NUXT JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, security, nuxt.js

I've tried to set CSP header for my site to load data from trusted resources

CSP blocks my local JS files. here is my nuxt.config.js:

```
const self = 'localhost:*'
render: {
    csp: {
        reportOnly:false,
        addMeta: true,
        policies: {
            'default-src': [self],
            'script-src': [self, 'unsafe-inline','strict-dynamic'],
            'style-src': [self,"'unsafe-inline'"],
            'img-src':[self,'data:'],
            'object-src':[self,'self']
        }
    }
},
```

Blocked files:

```
http://localhost:3500/_nuxt/runtime.js
http://localhost:3500/_nuxt/layouts/default.js
http://localhost:3500/_nuxt/pages/index.js
http://localhost:3500/_nuxt/commons/app.js
http://localhost:3500/_nuxt/vendors/app.js
http://localhost:3500/_nuxt/app.js
```

The error:

```
Refused to load the script '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'sha256-6SIdoCBgtiLdpIihMzGUvd5OCiaDdcIHhB8Tzkn9l8M='". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

It's header request shown in network tab for more details, It's strange but one time it gets same js file and one time it gives the error...

[image]

Comment: It should give you an error in the console, can you also copy the error from the console? It may give us a clue.

Comment: in `default-src` add `_nuxt` folder

Comment: @JakubKotrs I've added the error at end of my question

Comment: @EzizHudayberdiyev I added localhost:3500 everything in subdomain of it should be loaded, other things like styles are getting loaded with this way

Comment: `"script-src 'sha256-6SIdoCBgtiLdpIihMzGUvd5OCiaDdcIHhB8Tzkn9l8M='"` -> it looks like your config is not applied. You are running two servers, right? I have a feeling you are configuring the wrong one. The CSP should be configured on the server that's returning the HTML, not the one returning the assets.

Comment: @JakubKotrs No I am using nuxt, and nuxt only has one node server

Comment: Ok, I thought that since you are using a port, you may have two servers on two different ports. That's not it then. But anyway, the `script-src` is not what you set it to be, so the problem is that your config is not applied. I am not familiar with Nuxt to tell you more about that, sorry.

Comment: Check you response headers, is it matching with your configuration.

Comment: @EzizHudayberdiyev I've added screenshot of the request at end of my question, see it please

Comment: From where those blocked scripts come from, it should work if you add their path to CSP headers

Answer (score 0):

Examples below from mdn docs. Guess you problem can be solved by one of them. Please refer for more examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

Example 1

A web site administrator wants all content to come from the site's own origin (this excludes subdomains.)

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
```

Example 2

A web site administrator wants to allow content from a trusted domain and all its subdomains (it doesn't have to be the same domain that the CSP is set on.)

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' trusted.com *.trusted.com
```

Example 3

A web site administrator wants to allow users of a web application to include images from any origin in their own content, but to restrict audio or video media to trusted providers, and all scripts only to a specific server that hosts trusted code.

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; img-src *; media-src media1.com media2.com; script-src userscripts.example.com
```

Here, by default, content is only permitted from the document's origin, with the following exceptions:

Images may load from anywhere (note the "*" wildcard).
Media is only allowed from media1.com and media2.com (and not from subdomains of those sites).
Executable script is only allowed from userscripts.example.com.

Comment: Tnx but it doesn't helps I've read these